# Pandas read filename with spaces

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, import

I have a text file with 3 columns separated by spaces that I like to put into a dataframe.
I use the following construct to do this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(my_file, sep=' ', skiprows=4, names=('cola','colb','filename') )
```

That works fine, until I come across a filename that has spaces in it.

I cannot find an option in pd.read_csv to limit the number of columns and treat the last bit as 1 column.
How do I get such a file into a dataframe?

PS I know the format of the file is stupid, but that is out of my control

Comment: How does the file path look like?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this this way:

```
path = r"C:/Users/MY folder/Python/file name.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=' ', skiprows=4, names=('cola','colb','filename') )
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but that was not the problem.
The column 'filename' can have spaces, but i want to treat everyhting after the second space to be one column.

Answer (score 0):

Found one way of doing it:

```
df = pd.read_csv(tcs_file, sep='!@#', skiprows=4, engine='python', names=['line'])

df[['cola','colb','filename']] = df.line.str.split(" ", 3 , expand=True)

df.drop('line', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Not sure if this is the correct way of doing it, but as long as it works I am happy :-)